# How can I make Back to my Mac Screen Sharing go full screen?

Tags: snow-leopard, screen-sharing, back-to-my-mac

I've got two macs, both with the same monitor. When I use Back to my Mac Screen Sharing from Mac A to Mac B, I see the full screen of Mac B, but it's in a window on Mac A, and the image is scaled a little bit.

Also, since I set up all my machines the same way, the dock is on the bottom and has auto hide enabled for both. When I try to expose my doc on Mac B, My cursor winds up leaving the window and exposing the dock on Mac A.

Is there any way to get that screen sharing window to go full screen, the way something like VMWare or Parallels does? I tried other VNC clients, but Apple's Screen Sharing is the most responsive.

Answer (score 3):

Up to 10.5.4 included, it was possible to add, among other possibilities, a full screen item to Apple *Screen Sharing* application : [image: fullscreen].

But, from 10.5.5 they remove all these features and so, the simple *trick* becomes more *hacky*.

I don't know why Apple remove these options, but anyway, if you want them back and if you're not scared about tweaking *Screen Sharing* application with XCode or if you have a backup of Mac OS X 10.5.4, here's an [how-to](http://www.macworld.com/article/135649/2008/09/screen_sharing_buttons.html).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the only way to get full screen is with Apple Remote Desktop or a third party VNC client.

Answer (score 0):

The screen sharing client in OS X Lion supports the new [full screen mode](http://www.apple.com/macosx/whats-new/full-screen.html).